# How to get total time in sql

Tags: mysql

Good day, i need help though I have looked/searched other question like mine but it's not just what i am looking for. *That i want to get the total time* with this kind of data format. I have tried getting the total date by this query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(max(date(in_out)), min(date(in_out))) as datediffs,  FROM `tbl_tmpdtr` WHERE userid = 1002
```

and i get what i just needed, Now i want to get the total time and what i have tried so far is this query:

```
SELECT MAX(time(in_out))-MIN(time(in_out)) as minus FROM `tbl_tmpdtr` WHERE date(in_out) = '2015-05-01'
```

But the result was a whole number like this:

```
minus
90000
```

What am i missing? or lacking. What i want is to query the total time where date='2015-05-01'. Then after achieving that, the total time where id=1002.

i have this data in my database(mydb) table(tbl_tmpdtr):

```
id  |  userid  |  in_out             |  status
1   |  1002    | 2015-05-01 09:00:00 |  In
2   |  1002    | 2015-05-01 18:00:00 |  Out
3   |  1002    | 2015-05-02 09:00:00 |  In
4   |  1002    | 2015-05-02 18:20:00 |  Out
5   |  1002    | 2015-05-03 09:30:00 |  In
6   |  1002    | 2015-05-03 18:10:00 |  Out
```

Comment: I think it would be a problem with your client. It is interpreting 09:00:00 as 090000.

Comment: @sohaib: why? so how can make 090000 into 09:00:00?

Comment: Try converting it into some time or datetime type. I tried it out on my system and it gave me a `9` as an answer. That is what you want right?